# Regular expression grep fetch data between salary?

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, grep

```
E006:Jane:HR:9800:Asst
E005:Bob:HR:5600:Exe
E002:Barney:Purc:2300:PSE
E009:Miffy:Purc:3600:Mngr
E001:Franny:Accts:7670:Mngr
E003:Ostwald:Mrktg:4800:Trainee
E004:Pearl:Accts:1800:SSE
E009:Lala:Mrktg:6566:SE
E018:Popoye:Sales:6400:QAE
E007:Olan:Sales:5800:Asst
E019:Vish:Sales:3400:SE
```

3rd column is for salary.

List all employees whose salaries are between 2500 and 5500?

Comment: `grep` is not useful here. Use for instance `awk`.

Comment: @aioobe Ok but how can i fetch using awk?

Comment: Hi Viswanathan, did my solution solver your problem? If it, please accept the answer, if not, what are your precise requirements? It would be helpful if you provide an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

```
awk -F: '$4>2500 && $4 < 5500' file
```

Comment: +1: But note that '{print $0}' is redundant.  It is enough to just do: awk -F: '$4>2500 && $4 < 5500' file

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic but the question does say: _List **employees** whose salaries are **between** 2500 and 5500?_